# generator expression to read multiple csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I can load multiple csv files into multiple pandas dataframes i.e. `a`, `b` and `c` as shown below. However since `a`, `b` and `c` are part of a list, how can I use the `item_list` list to get items (i.e. `a`, `b` and `c`) instead of manually typing them?

```
item_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
file_list = [x + '.csv' for x in item_list]

a, b, c = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in file_list)
```

However if I do something like below, the three csv files are stored as list of dataframes.

```
item_list = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in file_list)  
list(item_list)
```

Result:

```
[  name
 0    a
 1    a
 2    a,
   name
 0    b
 1    b
 2    b,
   name
 0    c
 1    c
 2    c]
```

I simply want the dataframes to be stored in respective `a`, `b` and `c` dataframes without the need to type them explicitly. Imagine the situation when the list is large and not just three (i.e. `a`, `b` and `c`) in example shown above.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What error do you encounter?

Comment: Perhaps you want a list comprehension: `item_list = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in file_list]`

Comment: @Unmitigated kindly see the updated question.

Comment: If a list isn't what you want, maybe a dictionary might be better as it would allow you to access the dataframes using a key.

Comment: @Unmitigated Ok your suggestion actually works. I was just checking the item_list and each item is now a data frame and can be accessed by the item name. You can post as solution and I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```py
item_list = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in file_list]
```

Comment: Isn't this the same result they already showed in the question?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The asker originally used a generator expression, which was why they couldn't access individual elements easily.